# Is it possible to alter the default value for minOccurs in an XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

The [W3Schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp) says that the default value for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` for elements is `1`.

My XSD file is littered with elements that consist mainly of optional elements:

```
<xsd:element name="foo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element ref="one"   minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="two"   minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="three" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="four"  minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="five"  minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Manually specifying that each element is optional via `minOccurs` is tiresome and error-prone, which is why I am wondering if it is possible to alter the default value of `minOccurs` in the scope of the XSD.

Of course, there may be a better way to do things, in which case I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XSD has no facility for changing the default value of minOccurs in the schema for schema documents.

Your choices are essentially the same as for any case where a formal language specifies syntax you find inconvenient:  they include finding an editing interface that makes it less tedious to insert the minOccurs attribute, writing the initial draft of a schema document without minOccurs attributes and using XSLT (or the transformation technology of your choice) to supply them everywhere they are not already supplied, and putting up with the inconvenience.